# C++ malloc.c:2905: __libc_malloc: Assertion

Tags: c++, malloc

I have the following error, I don't have any idea what it is and how I can solve it.

```
malloc.c:2905: __libc_malloc: Assertion `!victim || ((((mchunkptr)((char*)(victim) - 2*(sizeof(size_t)))))->size & 0x2) || ar_ptr == (((((mchunkptr)((char*)(victim) - 2*(sizeof(size_t)))))->size & 0x4) ? ((heap_info *) ((unsigned long) (((mchunkptr)((char*)(victim) - 2*(sizeof(size_t))))) & ~((2 * (4 * 1024 * 1024 * sizeof(long))) - 1)))->ar_ptr : &main_arena)' failed.
```

I need your help!

Comment: what about sharing the statement(s) that caused the error ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your heap is corrupted.  This can be caused by bugs such as buffer overruns or writes to dangling pointers.  Running the program under a tool such as valgrind or Insure might help point out the bug.